# SQL Select String with Keyword

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, oledb

So lets say I had a db table, `Errors`

```
 [ID]    [ErrorDescription]
   1     "SELECT Name LIKE '*A*' Returned 0 Results"
   2     "SELECT Returned Multiple Results"
```

And I wanted to run a query like

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Errors 
WHERE ErrorDescription = 'SELECT Name LIKE '*A*' Returned 0 Results'
```

Is there a way to make this work? Currently I'm getting an

> OLEDB Exception "Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression"

when I'm trying to use an `OleDbDataAdapter` to run the query on an MS Access file. I looked around and couldn't find anything related to this, lots on using square brackets for keyword column names but not my particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have to escape the single-quotes, otherwise you're confusing the parser:

```
SELECT ID FROM Errors WHERE ErrorDescription ='SELECT Name LIKE ''*A*'' Returned 0 Results'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize that query. But, no matter how you handle this you will need to escape the quotes.

```
SELECT ID FROM Errors WHERE ErrorDescription ='SELECT Name LIKE ''*A*'' Returned 0 Results'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have single quotes within your string, which causes the parser to end the string literal at the first quote after `LIKE`.  Change your query to:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Errors 
WHERE ErrorDescription ='SELECT Name LIKE ''*A*'' Returned 0 Results'
```